# sendgrid port 2525 not working in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I am trying to use the Google Cloud offer for SendGrid in a Rails app.  In my config/environment/production.rb, I have:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp


# SMTP Settings for use with SendGrid
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = 
 {
 :user_name => "myusername", 
 :password => "mypassword",
 :domain => "mydomain",
 :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
 :port => 2525,
 :authentication => :plain,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

It connects instantly and instantly I get an error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
```

I can go there on the web and login with the same credentials, no problem.  Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Sendgrid typically requires port 587. Why are you using 2525?

Comment: because google cloud only allows 2525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an rvm issue.  Uninstalling and reinstalling rvm fixed this.